# Creating a certificate: A Primary Domain must be included

Tags: ssl-certificate

I'm new with CertifyTheWeb.

I trying to create a SSL certificate to use on my new site running on Windows Server 2019.

I am trying to create an to add my domain to create a certifiacte .

When I click Test I get the error message:

> A Primary Domain must be included.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It really has little to do with IIS itself, because you are using a third party system called CertifyTheWeb. So a new tag should be created. They have their own docs and a dedicated forum for discussion, https://community.certifytheweb.com so I don't think Stack Overflow is right place.

Comment: I tottaly hear what you are saying,
but I had a hard time finding an answer to this and I often use stackoverflow ' i thoght writing an answer to this will help others

Answer (score 1):

Step one and mosr importent is to specify your domains to the domain list !
This is where the ‘A primary domain must be included’ validation message is coming from, on the Certificate > Domains tab.

When I clicked the add button (or you can press enter) to add the domain to the list.
A certificate can cover many domains so step one is to add your domain to the list.